# Need a comma before an adverb as last word in sentence?

Tags: punctuation, adverbs, commas

When an adverb is the last word in a sentence, is it preferable to insert a comma before that word or to leave it as is (with no comma)?

For example:

> How many employees, roughly? **or** How many employees roughly?
>
> How long was the driveway, approximately? **or** How long was the driveway approximately?

Comment: The comma helps, really.

Comment: Or rearrange the word order: "Roughly how many employees *work here*?"  (It's quite good to have a verb in the sentence as well!).  "Approximately how long *is* the driveway?"  Presumably you want to know how long it *is now* - not how long it *was* at some unspecified time in the past?

Answer (score 7):

If the adverb applies to the verb specifically, as in

> I loved her passionately

then no comma is required.  If the adverb applies to the adjective from which it is separated (in your examples, *many* and *long*), a comma would be preferable. Your first example means

> How many employees work here, roughly?

and without the comma, the sense is that the employees work in a rough manner.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for helping make it more clear for me!