# Use of comma before adverb

Tags: grammar

I have seen cases of using commas before adverbs.

For example:

Sentence #1: I urgently need the pen.

Sentence #2: I need the pen, urgently.

Are both the above sentences acceptable?

Kind regards,
Kumar

Comment: In the second one, is a comma required? Commaphiles ;) may ask, then why not "I, urgently, need the pen."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a comma before an adverb as last word in sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319200/need-a-comma-before-an-adverb-as-last-word-in-sentence) No comma needed before a verb-modifying terminal adverb (though modern non-prescriptive flexibility allows the use of one here to signal a pause. A dash would signal a longer, more dramatic pause.)